# What is RabbitMQ clustering ?

Tags: ruby, rabbitmq, amqp

I've been using RabbitMQ ( AMQP ) with my ruby projects for a while now, anyways I just heard of RabbitMQ clustering , anyone can brief me about it is simple words , I need to know the difference between running ordinary RabbitMQ server and RabbitMQ clustering , why do I need it and how to implement it .

I need my solution to be scalable and to handle so many requests, I was thinking of the following implementation and I would love to know how to implement such a thing :

```
HA proxy->3 Clustered RabbitMQ instances
```

What is the fastest way along with the best ruby web server choice to handle request and simply parse it and send it to the appropriate queue .

With my current implementation I'm using Thin server and do something like the following but looking for better architecture which is faster and more scalable :

```
require "bunny"
require "thin"


@amqp ||= Bunny.new(:logging => false)
@amqp.start

@direct_exchange ||= @amqp.exchange('') 

app = Proc.new do |env|
  req = Rack::Request.new(env).params

  command = req['command'].strip rescue "no command"
  number  = req['number'].strip  rescue "no number"

  if command =~ /\A(create|c|r|register)\z/i      
    @direct_exchange.publish(number, :key => "create") 

  elsif command =~ /\A(update|u)\z/i
    @direct_exchange.publish(number , :key => "refresh") 

  end    

  [200, {'Content-Type' => "text/plain"} , command ]  

end

Rack::Handler::Thin.run(app, :Port => 4001)
```

I'm sure there is better implementation .

Any help/hint would be highly appreciated .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends where your real bottlenecks are, and what level of reliability you expect. But as a general rule of the thumb you may have:

- http load balancer balancing http request to several web servers
- N web servers handling http requests, parsing them end publishing commands to the RabbitMQ nodes
- RabbitMQ cluster consisting of M rabbit nodes
- K worker nodes, consuming messages from rabbit cluster and executing commands

Now the number of http servers can be different from RabbitMQ nodes. It depends, where your bottlenecks are going to be. Maybe you would need only one RabbitMQ node (so no cluster), or a few of them. If there are 2 for instance, than half of your http servers would be connected to one rabbitmq node, and half to other. Regardless of to which they are connected, they can publish to the same amqp exchange, and rabbtimq cluster will take a care  of handling 2 nodes and collecting everything published to that exchange under one hat, ragradless of the node http server was connected.

Th same logic goes for the "workers", i.e. servers consuming messages from the rabbitmq, and executing commands in them. There can be from 1 to K of them depending how much work they need to do. You would also connect them evenly to existing rabbitMQ servers.

Comment: Thanks Davorin for the explanation here , but I didn't get the part about RabbitMQ nodes , am i supposed to get new node for each HTTP server ? is there any simple presentation or tutorial to show that ? Thanks

Comment: Hi, I have extended my answer to clarify questions raised in your comment.